# IwNUI CTextFieldPtr to string

Tags: string, textbox, marmalade

I'm using a IwNUI CTextFieldPtr control and I would like to store/use the text attribute stored on the object in a string variable. I need to use that string but I have no clue on the documentation or examples on how to do it... I don't have a complete code sample either because what I'm asking should be pretty straight forward, such as:

```
CTextFieldPtr login_tUsername;
//textfield init here
std::string c_username;
login_tUsername->GetAttribute("text", c_username);
```

Please help me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And other approach, would be something like this, which is by far much closer to what I wanted to do:

```
CString value;
login_tUsername->GetAttribute("text", value);
std::string thestring = value.Get();
```

:)

(Credit goes billarhos [billarhos](https://devnet.madewithmarmalade.com/users/118/billarhos.html))

Answer (score 0):

Well... the best solution I found for this problem was something like this:

```
login_tUsername->SetEventHandler("textchanged", this, &OnUserEdit);

bool OnUserEdit(CTextField* textField, const char* text)
{
    c_username = text;
    return true;
}
```

I don't know why, but it seems you cannot use the textbox text attribute directly.

Cheers!